# Comprehensively of FBI Crime Reporting Program

Tags: usa, crime

Does anyone know how comprehensive the FBI crime reporting program is? For example, if I wanted to answer the question: how likely is crime x to happen, can I rely on this data* or should I assume there is a lot missing from local, country, state, etc

*I'd also need to take into account some crimes are likely not reported at all.

https://www.fbi.gov/services/cjis/ucr

Comment: Look under "Data considerations" and "Avoid ranking and comparisons" at https://crime-data-explorer.app.cloud.gov/ to see caveats. The page you yourself linked shows which agencies participate in reporting.

Comment: But is that comprehensive reporting or just optional reporting?

Comment: Just quoting the page, `The UCR Program includes data from more than 18,000 city, university and college, county, state, tribal, and federal law enforcement agencies. Agencies participate voluntarily and submit their crime data either through a state UCR program or directly to the FBI's UCR Program.`. I suppose you could look for a list of all law enforcement agencies, and see how many don't participate? Googling around suggests about 98% of agencies participate, but also that there are about 18K agencies total (slight contradiction).

Comment: `how likely is crime x to happen`: just to be whiny, remember that past performance does not imply future performance. The past doesn't always predict the future